# Is it possible to have lxtask as the sole task manager and to remove the gnome system monitor?

Tags: task-management

If so, having lxtask installed by now, which package am I supposed to uninstall? Otherwise, I'd simply uncheck the gnome system monitor in the lxpanel settings.
Kind regards,
schlossblick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is quite possible. On my [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) system, the `gnome-system-monitor` package is not even installed.

This is not an "essential" package, even on a Gnome/Unity system, and removing it should have no harmful effects at all. It should not affect any other Gnome software you may run on LXDE, such as the Nautilus file manager.

Comment: Yes, I know this configuration due to my former experience with lubuntu as well, but I've switched to ubuntu 12.04 and use lxde with nautilus as my default window manager. I'm afraid that by deinstalling the gnome sysem monitor, I'll erase more than I should in order to keep the system running.

Comment: LXDE is a desktop environment and Nautilus is a file manager (a.k.a. file browser). Neither is a [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager). If you're using a session of type LXDE or Lubuntu, you shouldn't need the GNOME System Monitor at all, even if your use Nautilus as your file manager. Even on a fully-fledged Ubuntu system, removing `gnome-system-monitor` shouldn't keep the system from working properly. Furthermore you seem to be asking about removing its applet from the `lxpanel` (or preventing it from starting with the graphical session). That's definitely safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate response, which helped to solved the problem. It was quite late in the night when I wrote my last answer, so of course, you're right, nautilus is my file manager, not my window manager. In regard to my question about removing the applet from lxpanel: I didn't intend it as a question but as a statement of the alternative road I'd have taken, if the preferred action - that is, deleting the gnome-system-monitor - hadn't been possible (aka lead to an instable/inoperable system). Kind regards,